# Is there way to change values of array given from another array

Tags: php, arrays, array-map

```
$original array [['type_of_activity'=>'م.ص','total'=>'0' ],['type_of_activity'=>'م.و','total'=>'0'],['type_of_activity'=>'م.ن','total'=>'0'],['type_of_activity'=>'م.خ','total'=>'0'],['type_of_activity'=>'م.ت','total'=>'0'],['type_of_activity'=>'و.ش','total'=>'0'],['type_of_activity'=>'ق.ع','total'=>'0'],
    ['type_of_activity'=>'م.و','total'=>'0'],['type_of_activity'=>'م.غ','total'=>'0'],['type_of_activity'=>'س.ن','total'=>'0'],['type_of_activity'=>'ح.ف','total'=>'0']]
```

that there areport based on this value

the return array from DB my be `['type_of_activity'=>'م.و','total'=>'5'],['type_of_activity'=>'م.غ','total'=>'10'],['type_of_activity'=>'س.ن','total'=>'15']`
 is there a way to map this array to the original array where the match keys
without losing any key or value

the result will be just 11 arrays within the original

[['type_of_activity'=>'م.ص','total'=>'0' ],
 [['type_of_activity'=>'م.ع','total'=>'0' ],
['type_of_activity'=>'م.و','total'=>'5'],['type_of_activity'=>'م.ن','total'=>'0'],['type_of_activity'=>'م.خ','total'=>'0'],['type_of_activity'=>'م.ت','total'=>'0'],['type_of_activity'=>'و.ش','total'=>'0'],['type_of_activity'=>'ق.ع','total'=>'0'], ['type_of_activity'=>'م.غ','total'=>'10'],['type_of_activity'=>'س.ن','total'=>'15'],['type_of_activity'=>'ح.ف','total'=>'0']],

Comment: Please go and check [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: use `$a3 = array_replace($a1, $a2);`

Comment: no it return the original without any change

Answer (score 1):

You can use [array_merge](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php),

```
$c = array_merge($a,$b);
print_r($c);
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/heDQK)

O/p

```
Array
(
    [mw] => 0
    [mg] => 5
    [ma] => 0
    [sn] => 0
    [fa] => 0
    [mn] => 10
)
```

Comment: It's the case when array_merge and array_replace works the same

Comment: i want ask more question that if i want to merge these arrary the result will duplicated

Comment: Can you elaborate? I ain't got you.